# Detecting mouse movement in a Screen Recording using Computer Vision

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, object-recognition

I wish to detect and track the mouse cursor in a screen recording video. My goal is to track the mouse cursor in the video and know about the events like closing of a window, exiting an application etc.

Use of normal CV algorithms to track objects does not work as the cursor and background are both dynamic and also there is not a very clear contrast between the two.

Is there a way to tackle this problem?

Comment: why video? why not log actions on the computer? I don't see how logging such things would help. you'll know if windows were closed or applications were quit but you don't know which ones unless you have a limited set of applications with distinct looks. so what's the point?

Comment: Is the stream compressed ?

Comment: @Piglet we do not have the logs.Our final goal is to train a cv algorithm which can detect the **on-exist crashes** by looking at the screen recording session. It would have been much easier if we had the event logs.

Comment: @YvesDaoust No the stream is not compressed.

Comment: so you want to tell me that you have access to a computer that allows you to capture it's screen 24/7 and track any movement but you don't have access to the system log? that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @piglet the data that i have is only the screen capture video recorded with citrix. System log is not available that's why we are taking this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the images are uncompressed, all pixel values of the cursor are known exactly and do not change as the cursor is moving (unless there is antialising or transparency on the edges ?).

Then an exact pattern search should do. (Slide the cursor to every possible position and check the matching of the pixels, until all pixels do match.)

---

If you arrange the search in such a way that the first cursor pixel tried has a different color than the background (the most frequent color), you will maximize the probability of immediate rejection. Even better if the first two pixels tried have different colors. By doing so, the number of pixels tried will get close to twice the image size, which is hard to beat.

---

Added by Mark Setchell below this line:

It seems cursors do change so you will need to take account of this:

[image]

Comment: Sound advice - I hope you don't mind my adding some thoughts. Feel free to delete/reject if you do.

Comment: Ok as you credited it to yourself. But I removed the "See note later" because I was not referring to that kind of change at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably detect the pointer using a HAAR Classifier: It is a machine learning based approach where a cascade function is trained from a lot of positive and negative images. It is then used to detect objects in other images. OpenCV already has [trained HAAR Classifiers](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html) built in for faces, eyes etc. but it should be possible to train your own for the cursor.

You can find a tutorial on how to train your own classifier [here](http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html) (how to do this is too extensive to include in this answer).

Comment: I think machine learning is overkill here. that's a straight forward template matching problem.

Comment: Perhaps it is a bit much, but do you think that template matching will perform well enough with the changing backgrounds?

Comment: if you exclude the background from your template, why not?

Comment: @diip_thomas: what makes you think that a HAAR classifier could beat template matching ? (or do you plan to train on all possible backgrounds in the world ?)

Comment: Training with several different backgrounds would help the classifier pick out most backgrounds, but I agree that template matching is probably more effective in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I use frame differencing for this problem combined with connected component analysis.

- grayscale your frames
- threshold the difference between the previous frame and new current frame
- find connected components in this binary image
- if you have one or 2 components, and they are small, it's likely your mouse